# How await expression works in Nodejs

Tags: node.js

I do not understand why `setImmediate` callback and `setTimeout` callback did not executed by this block of code.

```
async function a() {
  console.log("started");
  while (true) {
    await "c";
  }
}

setImmediate(() => console.log("setImmediate"));
setTimeout(() => console.log("setTimeout"), 0);
a();

console.log("duh");
```

The output is:

```
started
duh
```

Shouldnt the control is passed back to event loop when i use await expression in the `while(true)` loop? Which allow `setImmediate` and `setTimeout` callback to execute.

Comment: Your function `a()` is essentially an infinite loop that only allows other resolved/reject promises to be processed, never anything in the regular event loop because promises get served before the regular event loop.  Since your loop never finishes and always has another promise to serve, nothing in the event loop ever gets a chance to run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A pre-requisite to understanding this answer is to understand the JavaScript call stack, event loop, macrotask queue (a.k.a. task queue) and microtask queue. I won't elaborate much further because there's already a lot of material on this you can search for yourself. However a summary/simplification of the minimum to understand this answer is:

- **Event loop**: one loop of running **one** macrotask and **all** microtasks. After completion, it starts again with the next macrotask.
- **Macrotasks**: in your code, they are the script itself, `setTimeout` and `setImmediate`.
- **Microtasks**: in your code, they are Promises.

With that introduction, here's what is happening in your code:

1. The script is put on the macrotask queue. There's nothing else so this task is processed.
2. `setImmediate` puts its callback in the macrotask queue.
3. `setTimeout` puts its callback in the macrotask queue.
4. `a` is placed on the call stack. In each iteration of its `while` loop, something is placed in the microtask queue.
5. The log after calling `a` is run, as `a` is not `await`ed.
6. As we've reached the end of the script, we process all microtasks. However, there are infinite microtasks because of the infinite `while` loop.

As there are infinite microtasks, the next macrotask (the `setImmediate` callback) cannot be processed, so you never see the log from `setImmediate`'s callback.

## Further reading

- [Tasks, microtasks, queues and schedules, Jake Archibald](https://jakearchibald.com/2015/tasks-microtasks-queues-and-schedules/)
- [Event loop, JavaScript.info](https://javascript.info/event-loop)
- [Microtask queue, JavaScript.info](https://javascript.info/microtask-queue)